# Laravel - timezone saved in DB off by 5 hours

Tags: mysql, laravel

So, in Laravel's app.php I have the following timezone set:

```
'timezone' => 'America/Denver',
```

In MySQL settings I've got the same timezone. When I run `select now()` I get the current Denver time.

However, when I create a record in any table in the database, the `created_at` field (with default value set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) somehow ends up 5 hours ahead of Denver.

I believe it's somehow defaulting to UTC time, but I am not sure. All online resources I've found related to this issue claim that setting the timezone in Laravel should do the trick.

What else can I do to make sure I get the correct timezone saved in `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

I don't think server-wide PHP settings should have precedent over what's set in MySQL or in Laravel in this matter, but I have still gone ahead and tried editing the timezone in `php.ini` to America/Denver and no luck. It was previously commented out (not set to UTC).

Answer (score 2):

Use

`SET SESSION time_zone = 'America/Denver';`

In a raw query (`DB::select(DB::raw("SET SESSION time_zone = 'America/Denver'")`) before inserting and updating.

Test case

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   id INT
 , created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
); 

INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES(1);

SET SESSION time_zone = 'America/Denver';
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES(2);
```

**Possible results**

```
| id  | created_at          |
| --- | ------------------- |
| 1   | 2019-03-04 13:57:31 |
| 2   | 2019-03-04 06:57:31 |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q8uS815NmL2GX894sTgtSX/1)

Comment: This raw query returns the current `time_zone`: `SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);`

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent creates a new `Carbon` object when it sets the timestamp for `created_at`, it doesn’t use MySQL’s default. This should use `date_default_timezone_set`, which Laravel is setting.

Rather obvious answer is: have you tried clearing your config cache?

```
php artisan config:clear
```

---

*As an aside* it is generally advisable to always use UTC across everything, and only convert it to a local timezone at the last possible moment.

[From Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/):

```
// PS: we recommend you to work with UTC as default timezone and only use
// other timezones (such as the user timezone) on display
```

Comment: I've tried doing config:clear, as for the tip at the end the client wants to store everything in his timezone because he likes to export stuff directly from the database and he wants the data to be in the correct date in US time.

Comment: Ah. To be honest no human should have database access like that. I’d probably build a simple export function that allows you to download it as a file, and that could convert the dates to the chosen timezone. You’ll also find that using a timezone that changes because of Daylight Saving Time will probably screw with you a little, so again UTC is better to deal with this. Perhaps try https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-get-last-executed-mysql-query-in-laravel-example.html to see what’s actually going into MySQL?

Comment: I've checked, and what's actually going into MySQL is the UTC time. My client doesn't care about daylight savings, he wants his timezone in the database because his customers are local etc.

Comment: When I run my local version of the project, the times are saved correctly in the selected timezone. Could it be some type of server-wide settings forcing this? The production app is on AWS.